# "Could not load type XXX" error when I change output path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The default output path in VS 2010 in "Bin/" and this worked fine.  However, I changed it to "Bin/Debug" and "Bin/Release" and now I am getting the "Could not load type" error on my master page.

Comment: Did you check where the files went that got compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention a Master page, which is a feature of ASP.NET.

If you are using ASP.NET then you need to have your output path be Bin/, otherwise IIS will not know where to look for your files.

Comment: I think this is the likely reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check where your .exe ended up. Are you missing any .dlls from there?

If your dlls aren't being copied, right-click the reference in your Solution Explorer and hit Properties, and make sure "Copy Local" is set to true.

If they're dependencies of dependencies (i.e. they aren't being used directly by your application, but a dependency you're using needs it), you'll probably have to copy it over using a post-build event or something.